# Solving $x^{3} - 2 = 0$ and the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's start with a simple polynomial $f(x) = x^{3} - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. It is known that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and hence without any further information (i.e. working in field $\mathbb{Q}$ and ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) we can not distinguish the $3$ roots of $f$. <strike>The distinction between roots is only possible once we have the splitting field of $f$ available</strike>.

Now consider the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ which is a field (because $f$ is irreducible) and this field contains a member $x + (f(x))$ which is a root of $f(x)$. Moreover this field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\subset \mathbb{R}$.

> Why is this extension field obtained using quotient by $(f(x))$ give us the real root $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and not one of the other two roots? I mean while taking the quotient with $f$ we are just getting an extension field which depends on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)$ and we don't know for sure which of the three roots it will contain.

The same question however does not apply to all irreducible polynomials. Thus if we take $f(x) = x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1$ (or more simply $x^{2} + 1$) then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ contains all the roots of this polynomial.

**Update**: For the simple polynomial $x^{2} + 1$ I can show that both of its roots are in the extension field $\mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^{2} + 1)$. With some reasonable effort we can show the same for $f(x) = x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1$. I think we can also show that for $f(x) = x^{3} - 2$ the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ has only one root (I have not yet proved this for myself but I am sure I can).

> My real question is that even if we assume that this field has only one of the roots how do I know that this particular root is special and other two roots are more of a similar nature (ie this one is real and others are complex conjugates)?

---

It appears I have been misunderstood so I add more formalism and details. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^{3} - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. So $K$ has three elements $a, b, c$ each of which is a cube root of $2$ in $K$. Also we have $$K \supset \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{3} - 2) = L \supset \mathbb{Q}$$ <strike>My point is that the roots $a, b, c \in K$ are not indistinguishable from each other. Precisely we have one of these (say $a$) in $L$ and rest two ($b, c$) in $K$. Also there is automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sigma(b) = c$. But there is no automorphism of $K$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ and sends $a$ to $b$ (or $c$). I know this only by working in field $\mathbb{C}$. How do I know this without working in $\mathbb{C}$?</strike>

Thanks to DonAntonio, I understood the flaw in my reasoning. Also sorry to other people who answered for bearing with my nonsense comments. What I gather from the overall discussion is this:

**Summary**: The cubic $x^{3} - 2$ has three roots and they all lie in splitting field $K$. The intermediate field $L = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{3} - 2)$ contains only one of the roots (see last part of egreg's answer as to why $L$ can't have all the roots) and it is not possible to determine via algebra as to which of $a, b, c$ lie in $L$. Thus $a, b, c$ are indeed indistinguishable and any one (say $a$) can be supposed to lie in $L$ and the rest lie in $K$. And we can then prove that $K = L(b) = L(c)$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $L$ is of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $K$ is of degree $2$ over $L$. I think it is now easy to get the Galois group and show that it is indeed $S_{3}$.

Comment: The splitting field of $x^3-2$ contains three subfields which are cubic over $\mathbb Q$ (and generated by cube roots of $2$).  If you fix an embedding of $\overline {\mathbb Q}$ in $\mathbb C$ you can think of these as  $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3] 2],\mathbb Q[\zeta_3\sqrt[3] 2],\mathbb Q[\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3] 2]$ where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive cube root of $1$.  These fields are all isomorphic.  When you pick your $K$ which one did you have in mind?  And which embedding into $\mathbb C$ did you want?

Comment: To be clear:  you broke the symmetry between $a,b,c$ when you chose $K$.  If you want to, you can say that your favorite one was the real one, though you could just as easily call it $\zeta_3$ times the real one.  (Note that even there you haven't said which primitive cube root of $1$ you preferred).

Comment: Suppose I chose the complex one to be in $L$ then $L$ will be forced to have two roots and that is not the case.

Comment: What does 'the complex one" mean?

Comment: Really, all you know about your $K$ is that it can be generated over the rationals by $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^3=2$.  There is nothing intrinsically real about that.  I can embed $K$ to $\mathbb C$ in three ways and only one of those gives you a real subfield.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You're very last lines aren't accurate: **there is** an automorphism of $\;K/\Bbb Q\;$ sending the real root to any of the *other* two complex non-real roots. The action of $\;\text{Gal}\,\left(K/\Bbb Q\right)\;$ is **transitive** on the roots of *any* irreducible polynomial *which has least one root*, and thus *all* its roots, in $\;K\;$

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio for pointing out the error. I forgot the thing about transitive and its link to irreducible. Perhaps that's why I was not trying to use these terms as I am still a novice in these topics. My real question was that are roots of this cubic indistinguishable as far as algebra is concerned? My hunch is that they are distinguishable but it appears from your comments that they are indistinguishable. I will edit my post and get back to you again in few minutes.

Comment: @DonAntonio: please see my summary and let me know if I am correct.

Comment: @lulu: I misunderstood your comments initially, but now agree fully.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think that what you wrote after "Summary" is correct. Fields extensions and Galois Theory can be a little tough to grasp at first, but there are excellent books and articles on this subject, which imo is one of the most beautiful and breath-taking in the undergraduate curriculum. Good luck and enjoy!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks for the encouragement. I do have some good books with me but I am not exactly a student at present so I have to do self study and I have found that MSE is a much bigger help than all the books I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this extension field obtained using quotient by $(f(x))$ give us the real root $\sqrt[3]{2}$?

It doesn't. The field $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ contains a cube root of $2$, that is, an element $b$ such that $b^3=2$. There is *no* canonical embedding of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $b\mapsto\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Actually there are exactly *three* embeddings of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$, one for each cube root of $2$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

And, yes, $K$ has a single element whose cube is $2$, because it is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

---

The Galois group of $x^3-2$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$) has six elements (it is $S_3$). This is different from the cases of $x^2+1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, because their Galois groups are cyclic, so when one root is added, also all the other roots are. Since the group $S_3$ is generated by at least two elements, you need two roots for generating the splitting field.

---

Let's work in the field $K$, where $b$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3-2$. Then we have, over $K$,
$$
x^3-2=(x-b)(x^2+bx+b^2)
$$
for some $u$ and $v$ in $K$. Can a root of $x^2+bx+b^2$ belong to $K$? No, because the discriminant is $-3b^2$ (work it out).

Comment: It appears that my question has been misunderstood. I will provide update in my question with more inputs.

Comment: Please see the last part of my question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh See my addition

Comment: How do we know that the Galois of $x^{3} - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has $6$ elements if we don't have any information about complex numbers? I think I am still not able to pin point my problem very clearly.

Comment: The reason we think the Galois Group is $S_{3}$ is because we explicitly mention the splitting field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{-3}) \subset \mathbb{C}$. Without this representation of $K$ I wonder how we conclude that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Cardan's formulas.

Comment: @user1952009: my question is how do I get the splitting field $K$ if we don't know anything about complex numbers?

Comment: Ok so the techniques of abstract algebra don't provide anyway to obtain concrete information about splitting field unless we use classical methods to solve equations? Like using quotient by $(x^{3} - 2)$ I got the intermediate field, can't i get the splitting field in similar manner?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You can try to see $K$ as a matrix field. For example $\mathbb{Q}(i) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix})$. And $K = \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$ for some ideal $I$

Comment: Sorry for all the previous comments. I am learning these topics and trying to make clear understanding of the issues involved here. I have added a summary at the end of my question which is hopefully correct.

Comment: Your last update about the working in $K$ is perhaps what was needed all along for me to clear up my confusion. +1 and accept.

Comment: "$K$ has a single element whose cube is $\sqrt[3]{2}$" - is this correct or did you mean to write, "$K$ has a single element whose cube is $2$"? - I am a beginner so I may be wrong!

Comment: @user93353 Misprint, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)$ is a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$
but $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^3-2)$ isn't. A Galois extension will contain all zeros
of its defining polynomial; a non-Galois extension won't.

Comment: How do I distinguish these two cases without actually working in field $\mathbb{C}$? Moreover even if I assume that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{3} - 2)$ contains only one root, how do I know that it contain the real root and not one of the complex roots?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh $K=\Bbb Q[x]/(x^3-2)$ contains no such thing as a "real root" or a "complex root". It contains an element $a$ with $a^3=2$. Over $K$, $X^3-2$ factorises, as $(X-a)(X^2+aX+a^2)$. But $X^2+aX+a^2$ is irreducible over $K$; therefore $a$ is the only cube root of $2$ in $K$.

Comment: I think you still don't understand my question. It is possible to prove that roots of $x^{2} + 1$ or $x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1$ are indistinguishable from each other as far algebraic operations are concerned. But this is not the case for $x^{3} - 2$. The three roots of this polynomial are not interchangeable and it must be possible to know this just using field extensions.

Comment: The roots of $X^3-2$ **are** "indistinguishable from each other as far as algebraic operations are concerned". They generate the sextic field $L=\Bbb Q(2^{1/3}, \sqrt{-3})$ which has an automorphism group transitively permuting the cube roots of $2$ therein.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know why the Galois group of $K=\Bbb Q(a,b,c)$
permutes $a$, $b$, $c$ arbitrarily without working in $\Bbb C$?

By Eisenstein's criterion $X^3-2$ and $X^2+3$ are irreducible
over $\Bbb Q$. Let $a$ and $s$ be zeros of them in some extension field.
Let $K=\Bbb Q(a,b)$. It's easy to prove that $|K:\Bbb Q|=6$. Moreover
$K\cong \Bbb Q[X,Y]/\langle X^2-2,Y^2+3\rangle$
Let $b=(-1+s)a/2$ and $c=(-1-s)a/2$. Then in $K$ we have
$$X^3-2=(X-a)(X-b)(X-c).$$

An automorphism of $K$ must send $a$ to one of $a$, $b$ and $c$
and $s$ to one of $s$ and $-s$. Since
$K\cong \Bbb Q[X,Y]/\langle X^2-2,Y^2+3\rangle$ any such pair of
choices induces an homomorphism from $K$ to $K$ and on
dimension grounds this must be an isomorphism.

The automorphism mapping $a$ to $b$ and fixing $s$ maps $b$ to $c$
and $c$ to $a$.

The automorphism fixing $a$ and mapping $s$ to $-s$ swaps $b$ and $c$.

Combining these we get automorphisms of $K$ permuting $a$, $b$ and $c$ arbitrarily.

Note that throughout I have made no use of $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I think the OP thought there aren't elements in  Gal$\,\left(K/\Bbb Q\right)\;$ mapping the real root to the non-real roots of $\;x^3-2\;$ . I addressed this in a comment below the question.

Comment: Sorry for all the previous comments. I am learning these topics and trying to make clear understanding of the issues involved here. I have added a summary at the end of my question which is hopefully correct.